# generating url parameters from array

Tags: php, arrays, url, syntax

Let's say I have the following array :

```
$params
= array(
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'baz' => array('qux', 'qux2', 'qux3')
);
```

is there a pre-built function in php so :

```
the_function($params);
```

outputs

```
'foo=bar&baz[]=qux&baz[]=qux2&baz[]=qux3'
```

?

Note : i am asking for a pre-built function, I can code the function myself. Just making sure I am not coding something already existing.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with only one function call of a php function

Comment: not that I know of. It looks pretty much way too specific to make a function for, doesn't it?

Comment: That wouldn't be more than few lines of could why you even bother!

Answer (score 0):

How come nobody suggested this before. `http_build_query()` is what you were looking for.

```
$params = array('foo'=>'bar','baz'=>array('qux','qux2','qux3'));
echo urldecode(http_build_query($params));
// foo=bar&baz[0]=qux&baz[1]=qux2&baz[2]=qux3
```

A few caveats you might have to be aware of :

- the resulting string is urlencoded (use `urldecode()` as I did above if necesary)
- array indexes are present in the query string

Some of the comments in the documentation page can help with the latter if needed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php